# Plot only diagonal entries with data.frame of many time-series in R

Tags: r, plot

I have several time series, which when I plot using,

```
plot(na.omit(d))
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

Instead of this entire matrix of plots, I only want the ones from the diagonal. In other words, I don't want to plot the combinations of different time series.

The following very messy code achieves what I want, but I was wondering if there were a simpler, more compact way to accomplish this:

```
png('./Pictures/acf1.png')
plot(acf(na.omit(f$C1)))
png('./Pictures/acf2.png')
plot(acf(na.omit(f$C2)))
png('./Pictures/acf3.png')
plot(acf(na.omit(f$C3)))
png('./Pictures/acf4.png')
plot(acf(na.omit(f$C4)))
png('./Pictures/acf5.png')
plot(acf(na.omit(f$C5)))
png('./Pictures/acfCO2.png')
plot(acf(na.omit(f$MLCO2)))

png('./Pictures/pacf1.png')
plot(pacf(na.omit(f$C1)))
png('./Pictures/pacf2.png')
plot(pacf(na.omit(f$C2)))
png('./Pictures/pacf3.png')
plot(pacf(na.omit(f$C3)))
png('./Pictures/pacf4.png')
plot(pacf(na.omit(f$C4)))
png('./Pictures/pacf5.png')
plot(pacf(na.omit(f$C5)))
png('./Pictures/pacfCO2.png')
plot(pacf(na.omit(f$MLCO2)))
```

Maybe something similar to this?

```
for(i in d) 
{
    png(PACF$i.png)
    plot(pacf(na.omit(d$i)))
}
```

Comment: I can't really make heads or tails of this question. Can you try to edit it to make your specific problem a bit clearer?

Comment: @joran: this is bazaar, let the best solve the puzzle :D AndresT derypted this. Solved. For me, it is hard to make this question clearer, can you now see what what I meant?

Comment: Yes, now I see what you meant. See my edits for a example of how to write a clear question.

Comment: @joran: thanks. Perhaps, I think just too algorithmic when asking: "input" and "output", dot. Yes, that is plain English :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 for(i in 1:ncol(d)){
png(paste('c:/zzz/',i,'.png',sep =''))
plot(pacf(na.omit(d[,i])))
dev.off()
}
```

For './Pictures/pacfCO2 try something like:

```
png(paste('./Pictures/pacf',i,'.png',sep=''))
```

Comment: Thank you, luckily there are still literate users :P Exactly.